# BST preorder traversal question. why am I getting the wrong answer using queue? javascript

Tags: javascript, iteration, binary-search-tree

I'm using queue to iteratively solve a BST preorder traversal question. I know for stack, it's reversed and it works, but with queue I'm getting the wrong answer. Why? Thanks

```
var preorderTraversal = function(root) {
   if (root == null) {
     return [];
   }

   const queue = [];
   const result = [];

   queue.unshift(root);

   while(queue.length > 0) {
     let current = queue.shift();
     result.unshift(current.val);

     if (current.right) queue.unshift(current.right);
     if (current.left) queue.unshift(current.left);
   }

   return result;
};
```

Comment: If you work out an example with paper and pencil, you may understand why a queue is not the correct data structure for preorder traversal.

Comment: Why? Because a stack and a queue behave differently. Why do you expect to get the same result when you change your implementation from a stack to a queue?

Answer (score 0):

You are using `queue` as a stack, since you shift values in and out *at one and the same side* of the array, which is what a stack does ("LIFO (last in, first out)"). So it actually works, but as you state at the start, it works in reverse because you *prepend* the values to the result. If you would *append* them, it would be fine:

```js
var preorderTraversal = function(root) {
   if (root == null) {
     return [];
   }

   const queue = [];
   const result = [];

   queue.unshift(root);

   while(queue.length > 0) {
     let current = queue.shift();
     result.push(current.val); // Append instead of prepend

     if (current.right) queue.unshift(current.right);
     if (current.left) queue.unshift(current.left);
   }

   return result;
};

// Add the Node class to facilitating creating a binary tree (a binary search tree)
class Node {
    constructor(val) {
        this.val = val;
        this.left = this.right = null;
    }
    add(val) {
        if (val < this.val) {
            if (this.left) this.left.add(val);
            else this.left = new Node(val);
        } else {
            if (this.right) this.right.add(val);
            else this.right = new Node(val);
        }
    }
    print(tab="") {
        if (this.right) this.right.print("  " + tab);
        console.log(tab + this.val);
        if (this.left) this.left.print("  " + tab);
    }
}

// Demo
let root = new Node(4);
for (let val of [2, 6, 1, 3, 5, 7]) root.add(val);
console.log("The tree (with root at the far left): ");
root.print(); // Print the tree
console.log("preorder traversal: ", ...preorderTraversal(root));
```

Again, this is a *stack* solution, not a *queue* solution -- despite the variable name. JavaScript array methods give a "deque" interface to arrays, and so you can easily add and remove elements from either side of the array.

If you exclusively use `push` and `pop` you'll have a stack behaviour, and if you replace those with `unshift` and `shift`, you'll **still** have a stack behaviour.

You'll get a queue behaviour when you use the pair `push`/`shift` or the pair `unshift`/`pop`, but that will not be useful for implementing a pre order traversal. That is what you would use for a *level* order (breadth-first) traversal.

Comment: Any feedback on this answer?